# Animation Nodes - Why Time info Node does not update Frames?

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I have this problem:

[image]

As you can see Viewer shows 0.0 while it should show frame 118 or 119..
Frame node does not update while scrubbing in timeline. Anyone had this problem as well?

I've checked "Frame changed" and/or "Always" in Auto execution tab. But it does no effect anything.. Maybe I missed something else

Comment: If you have auto execution enabled it should work. I tested it, it works for me. Can you give us some more info and/or provide your blend-file? I'll have a look later.

Comment: Thats the problem.. In a new scene everything worked.. in this one it does not.. I did not get to create this scene from the start, so I don't know if anything was pressed there or not.. that is why I asked if there is any other place to turn on/off things like refresh and stuff.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/getting_started/execution.html) on execution?

Comment: Ok.. I found something Interesting.. The scene had a couple of Sub scenes created in it. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/194901346183413761/514409360852647936/unknown.png  And the Time info node works in the "Directory" (I guess First) scene. Bud does not work in "Hero" and in "Portal" scenes..

Comment: Ok.. I think I've was able to duplicate the problem. I'v created new scene. And added a couple of more subscene to it.. and the problem repeated it self. In the primary scene Node tree worked.. in the subsequent ones - did not.. Now The question is.. How do I link Animation Nodes with the exact Scene?

Comment: You need to add tag animation-node so to get your question answered quickly. Presently, you have only two separate tags animation and nodes, not the same as animation-nodes.

Comment: I just added animation-nodes under your question a while ago.

Comment: Thank you .. Will know that in the future!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign scene for the Node Tree. The option can be found in N-panel of Animation Nodes window.

For Blender 2.8+

[image: for blender 2.8+]

for older versions of Blender.

[image: scene select]

Just click on drop down menu and select the scene which you are currently working on.

Comment: We have not explained that in the documentation at all, and we intend to fix it. Thanks for bringing this up. Please accept your own answer if it answers your questions.